# How to compile greenDao example without eclipse?

Tags: greendao

How to compile GreenDao examples and DaoExampleGenerator without eclipse?

Comment: [this diff](https://github.com/yigit/greenDAO/commit/1e60d467aac6ece99078d45b422301768fe9533a) has an ant task to compile dao generator.

Comment: This is help. I have to use eclipse to export an ant build.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Studio to do it.

Gradle is integrated and download dependent libraries.

Just be aware on the paths in Android studio (uses the main project path containing all modules (one module in android studio is a project in Eclipse).

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

dropdown on the run button click on Edit Configuration, then, click + button and add new Application and on config : Check on below image then click apply and ok.

[image]

Next what you need to do is on dropdown, choose your daogenerator then run the application it will compile the dao class

[image]

then it should looks like above and click run. It should works!

Good luck!!